# How to change two different global variables from inside a Function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

this is my first question here in StackOverflow..

I'm studying JavaScript right now and I'm trying to refactor some code to make it easier to read and shorter.

I need to add a point to a player score in a display when a button is clicked, so I created a function "addPoint" that takes 2 paramenters, one is the player score, and the other is the player display where I display the points...

This is what I have...

```
var p1 = document.querySelector("#p1");
var p2 = document.getElementById("p2");
var dis1 = document.querySelector("#dis1");
var dis2 = document.getElementById("dis2");
var btnReset = document.querySelector("#reset");
var input = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
var winDis = document.querySelector("#num");
var p1Score = 0;
var p2Score = 0;
var gameOver = false;
var winScore = 5;

p1.addEventListener("click", function() {
  addPoint(p1Score, dis1);
});

p2.addEventListener("click", function() {
  addPoint(p2Score, dis2);
});

btnReset.addEventListener("click", function() {
  reset();
});

input.addEventListener("change", function() {
  winDis.textContent = this.value;
  winScore = Number(this.value);
  reset();
});

function addPoint(pScore, display) {
  if (!gameOver) {
    pScore++;    
    if (pScore === winScore) {
      display.classList.add("winner");
      gameOver = true;
    }
    display.textContent = pScore;    
  }
}

function reset() {
  p1Score = 0;
  p2Score = 0;
  dis1.textContent = p1Score;
  dis2.textContent = p2Score;
  dis1.classList.remove("winner");
  dis2.classList.remove("winner");
  gameOver = false;
}
```

The thing is that when I click on any of the buttons, the function adds **1** to the score, but it never changes the global variables **p1Score** or **p2Score**, so whenever I **click** a player **button** again, it shows **1** all the time because it takes the **initial value** of those variables, so my function it's not returning the new value to those variables, my question is what am I missing here? I can't find an answer here to my particular problem.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is this: 
When you do this `addPoint(p1Score, dis1);` you are not passing the variable `p1Score` to your function, but only its current value.
Inside the `addPoint` function this value, that is just a number, is assigned to a new variable, the argument `pScore`.
So, when you do `pScore++` you are adding 1 to the new variable but not to the original `p1Score`. You can modify this variable only by explicitly doing `p1Score = // something`. One solution is to move the adding inside the event handler:

```
p1.addEventListener("click", function() {
  p1Score++
  addPoint(p1Score, dis1);
});
function addPoint(pScore, display) {
  if (!gameOver) {   
    if (pScore === winScore) {
      display.classList.add("winner");
      gameOver = true;
    }
    display.textContent = pScore;    
  }
}
```

or use an object (whose properties are accessible as strings) to store your scores:

```
var p1 = document.querySelector("#p1");
var p2 = document.getElementById("p2");
var dis1 = document.querySelector("#dis1");
var dis2 = document.getElementById("dis2");
var btnReset = document.querySelector("#reset");
var input = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
var winDis = document.querySelector("#num");

var scores = {
    "p1": 0,
    "p2": 0
}
var gameOver = false;
var winScore = 5;

p1.addEventListener("click", function() {
  addPoint('p1', dis1);
});

p2.addEventListener("click", function() {
  addPoint('p2', dis2);
});

btnReset.addEventListener("click", function() {
  reset();
});

input.addEventListener("change", function() {
  winDis.textContent = this.value;
  winScore = Number(this.value);
  reset();
});

function addPoint(player, display) {
  if (!gameOver) {
    scores[player] += 1;
    if (scores[player] === winScore) {
      display.classList.add("winner");
      gameOver = true;
    }
    display.textContent = scores[player];    
  }
}

function reset() {
  scores.p1 = 0;
  scores.p2 = 0;
  dis1.textContent = 0;
  dis2.textContent = 0;
  dis1.classList.remove("winner");
  dis2.classList.remove("winner");
  gameOver = false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much man, the first solution you gave me actually works perfectly, I just need to add **pxScore++;** just **before calling the function** and this does the job perfectly, now I understand better!

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to access global variables from inside a function, you **do not need to pass the values of those global variables** as function parameters.

Instead, you can refer to the global variables directly from inside the function.

Why does this work? How can a reference to a variable inside a function mean anything when that variable is absent from the function scope?

It's because any references to variables absent from any present scope will lead the javascript engine to search the scope above (and if the variables are absent there too, it will search the next scope above etc. all the way up to the global scope).

So, if you have these global variables:

```
const dis1 = document.querySelector("#dis1");
let p1Score = 0;
```

then, instead of:

```
p1.addEventListener("click", function() {
  addPoint(p1Score, dis1);
});
```

and

```
function addPoint(pScore, display) {
  if (!gameOver) {
    pScore++;    
    if (pScore === winScore) {
      display.classList.add("winner");
      gameOver = true;
    }
    display.textContent = pScore;    
  }
}
```

you can write:

```
p1.addEventListener("click", function() {
  addPoint();
});
```

and

```
const addPoint = () => {
  if (!gameOver) {
    p1Score++;    
    if (p1Score === winScore) {
      dis1.classList.add("winner");
      gameOver = true;
    }
    dis1.textContent = p1Score;    
  }
}
```

Comment: Mmm ok, but this way, don't I have to declare 1 function for every player? Because in your example you're using p1Score++; inside the function which will handle player 1 but, I have to repeat the same function in case I click the p2 button isn't it? Maybe i'm not seeing something here... I apologyse in that case..

Comment: Oh I understand but I think that's a little advance for me right now, I'll have it in mind tho. I'm sure it will come up later on the course. Thank you very much for your answer!